# frequent net::ERROR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, server, connection

I've built website (http://phedikholamun.gov.np/tabinfo.php) using php. I'm tired searching solution of **net::ERROR_CONNECTION_RESET.**

[image]
Actually, it doesn't occur every time of loading website. But frequently it takes place. First fall, browser shows this error (only 2/3 second), after that website start to load. Though it seems minor issue, In fact, It is irritating and frustrating. I've  wasted lot of time to solve this error . While searching in internet, I found this problem can be occurred because of :

- missing mysql close syntax
- httpd config
- nature of web hosting

I've tried to solve this problem by addressing above issues. But none of these work. How to solve this problem.

Comment: The website loaded every time i've tryed. What Browser are you using? This sounds more likly to be a lokal internet issue or firewall issue... And the question should be moved to http://www.serverfault.com because it's not about programing

Comment: Thanks @Raymond Nijland for prompt response. I've used chrome. Mainly in mobile(android), this problem is occurred. I think it is problem in php/mysql code, so i've posted in programming forum.